# Insert Data From Access Database to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

**Desired result and why:**

I have a lot of old Access databases that we are trying to get to SQL Server, and I'm essentially trying to make the Access DB the "middleman" so our old programs can still read/write to them but the information will also be saved in SQL Server. We need the middleman because of how interconnected these tables are through various programs we are rewriting in modern languages. Once we rewrite all of them we will cut the cord and live in SQL Server, but this will take a lot of time.

**What I've tried:**

We tried creating a linked table to SQL Server and renaming it so it would take the place of the original table. After doing this the table stopped receiving data so we quickly reverted back.

In order to investigate this I created ***Table B*** which is just another linked table to SQL Server, and then tried using the After Insert macro on ***Table A*** to send any new rows to the linked table but nothing happens. If I manually add a record to ***Table B*** it carries over to SQL Server just fine, but I can't get ***Table A*** to send data to ***Table B***. I created ***Table C*** that is just a local access table and if I manually add a record to ***Table A*** it does show up in ***Table C***. No errors at all, it just doesn't do what I need it to do.

I'm lost on how to accomplish this and open to any help or suggestions on how to move forward with this. One thing to note though, is that most of the access databases I have are not using forms at all which is I'm trying to take the macro route instead of any VBA. I need these to trigger without any interaction from the user.

Comment: Don't use some middle table approach. You migrate all data to sql server, link the tables from Access, and you should be good to go. Attempting to introduce temp tables or whatever? You just going to break boatloads of code. If you migrate the data, then all code, and in fact 99% of the application will now work as before. You can then choose to introduce say some views for better report performance, but for the most part, first step is to migrate data, and then use linked tables. And your forms should in near all cases also just "work" without changes.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I did try this, but for some reason any programs writing to the Access DB stop writing. I can manually add entries to the linked tables and they carry over to SQL fine, but something seems to be stopping programs from being able to write to those linked tables. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, from access, open up any of those linked tables - can you edit? No use trying to run forms + code unless a simple open of a table and editing is allowed? However, while Access local tables can be edited without a primary key (PK), any and all sql server tables ALL MUST have a PK - in most cases we use a auto number in Access, and in sql server, that becomes a PK and a "identify" column (the auto increment part). But yes, all tables now must have a PK setting. I would set this in Access, and then migrate again using  the migration assistant.

Comment: It is thus no doubt a VERY good idea to get sql server express (free edition) installed, setup and running on your local dev computer. so, those linked tables from Access should allow edits. If they don't, then the PK is missing.

Comment: I am able open and edit the tables, and it is being sent to SQL when I do it from my machine. There is no PK in the Access DB tables though, and I don't have a PK for SQL either since I thought keeping them 1to1 would be the way to go. I'll try setting a PK in Access and migrate again to see if that helps.

Comment: You set ZERO and NOTHING in the access client side - ONLY exception if you using sql server views. You set the PK in sql server, and then have to re-link your table(s).  You can double check tables now in access. Right click on the linked table, choose design mode (ignore read only warning). What does the linked table look like? Does the linked table show a PK? But for linked tables - you NEVER set or attempt to set PK in access client. You do this sql server side, and then re-link your tables. But, check the linked table in design mode - does it show a PK? (in most cases edits fail without PK

Comment: Also, while you are looking at the linked table, check date columns - if they show as text and not datetime, then STOP EVERYTHING until you resolve that issue first.

Comment: So I should add an autonumber ID field to the access side, but not set it to PK in Access and instead do that in SQL? The only unique field I have in the Access DB is a time stamp as the DB is written to every 5 minutes, but I'd rather use a standard incremental number. Everything else is a number (int) aside from the single Date/Time field. There are a few that will need to be floats on the SQL side though.

Comment: You can't modify a linked table structure in access. So if the linked table in question does not have a PK id, then yes, you have to modify the table in sql server and re-link. However, it would have been better (and easier) to add the PK auto number in Access before you migrate the table(s) to sql server. So, once the data (tables) been sent to sql server, then you can't modify the linked table structure in access. You have to modify the sql server table and then re-link. So if you want to add a new field, or make changes to the columns/structure, you now do that in sql server, and relink

Comment: The migration wizard has a check box (option) to add PK autonumber automatic to any and all tables during a migration. So, it really comes down to how many tables you have. For a few, then just add the PK autonumber in sql server and re-link. If you have 60 tables, then that's going to be quite a bit of work. But as a general rule, any and all tables before migration should have a PK setup.

Comment: I started this over from scratch, and I created a PK ID field in the two tables I am migrating with AutoNumber. I went through the migration wizard and had 0 issues, the data came over to SQL just fine, but I am still unable to get new records added. When I open the Access DB with linked tables it prompts me for the SQL credentials so I put them in and can view the tables. They are showing the PK in design view, but when the Access DB is being written to via another application it doesn't add any new records to the linked tables at all. I just don't understand what else could be missing.

Comment: Ok, since you don't have a lot of tables, then you can delete them, and then re-link them. (it really depends on how many tables you have). During the table re-link (first time - new relink of tables - assuming you deleted existing links, there is a [x] remember password check box - you need to check that box to prevent logon prompt. (are you using sql logon, or windows auth for the logon?

Comment: >>but when the Access DB is being written to via another application (wow!!!  ok stop the press here!!! - WHEN DID THIS HUGE WHOPPER come into this discussion!!! - that other program is to now write to sql server - not linked tables in access anymore.  You might get this to work, but you first 100% has to get rid of that sql logon prompt. And it will depend VERY much on how that other software operates - but the data now not in access anymore, so that other applcation don't need access anymore - does it????

Comment: I was trying to find some middle ground in this because we have about 30 something databases (over 400 tables total), and around 70 different applications using these db's/tables. Some are more woven together than others, but the hope was that we could use access as a middle man until the applications are all rewritten. Then we could easily go back and cut the cord from Access and just use SQL. The more I try though, it's appearing that we will just need to rewrite these applications in clusters and cut the cord that way. I'm open to any suggestions you may have to solve that problem though.

Comment: I picked a fairly simple and small Access DB to use for testing this solution out, but there is a much bigger goal behind that.

Comment: see my answer below - but if a linked table works for edits, deletes and inserts, then you can then and only then start to test local code and data operations.  and you for sure have to eliminate the sql logon prompts that appear.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the tool dedicated to this task:

[SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access (AccessToSQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/access/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-access-accesstosql?view=sql-server-ver15?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-5002361)

Comment: Thanks, I'm definitely going to look into this tool. When looking at the linked table section of the link you provided I see: "Your Access tables remain in Access, but are not updated together with SQL Server or SQL Azure updates. After you link the tables and verify functionality, you might want to delete your Access tables." Does this just mean that the access table is no longer being written to and is in fact just a middleman of data at this point? So an old application can still read from it, and anything written will go to SQL?

Comment: The original tables will be renamed, that's all.

Comment: Yes, if you migrate data from Excel to say access, then the orginal data is not much use anymore - except for history sake. Same here, once you migrated those tables to sql server, then the original tables are not of much any use anymore. Your data, and the access applcation is now to use the sql server tables, and any updates to a linked table to sql server means you directly updating and using the data in sql server now. What you choose to do with the older data in access tables? That's up to you. After migration to sql server, and you link tables, then access application should work fine

Comment: I tried using the tool on various occasions and Access db's, and while it does convert the DB over to SQL, it will only update back and forth with manual inputs on the linked tables. Any programs hitting the Access DB is unable to write to it which of course means SQL never gets it either. I tried using a DSN file to save credentials, but I am just unsure of where this is going wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: I admit, that I don't understand your scenario. SSMA is a _migration_ tool, not some kind of "linking" tool.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are from comments some new and signficant moving parts here.

For example, data is to be migrated to sql server. As noted, EVEN in access land, all and every table needs and should have a PK for the "basic" data base operations. While it is possible to do some work, and say some importing of data, the instant one wants some forms, VBA code and starts to build a working applcation? Then all tables should have a PK.

And of course if you moved the data to sql server, then it not going to make a lot of sense to have OTHER applcations attempt to modify the linked tables in access, since the data is not in Access anymore!!! Those other sources in theory should thus also hit sql server, and not attempt to use what amounts to a link on a linked table.

However, it does depend. For example, if you use vb.net code and say open a access database, you CAN in fact have that vb.net code open a access table, and in fact it can be a linked table. (however, it would make a WHOLE lot more sense for the vb.net code to open and hit sql server - introduction of a link on a link is going to be problematic.

However, in testing, I have found that say vb.net can open a access table, and even if it is a link, then access will translate though the jet engine (the access data engine), and you can do this.

However, data macros and table triggers on existing access tables? They might work on linked tables, but you of course need to ensure that the linked table does allow edits, and allows inserts. Only AFTER one has verified that you can click on a linked table to sql server - can edit, and then add should one mess around with data macros and triggers on say local tables.

it also depends on what the new software tools and platform is being used here.

But, from a basic database point of view - and general data mangement?

All code, and designs should assume, and be designed around the assumption that each row of data has a PK. This is not always possible, but is a RARE use case.

Practical data management - and use of a database should from both table designs, and from workflow designs, and from a developer point of view assume the concept of a PK row id. Without such assumptions, then you not in the software industry anymore - but in a hack field, and one that will result in great future difficulty when attempting to build work flows and build general information systems.

So, with above in mind: Your table B - it has to work as a valid sql server table.

The sql server table(s). They need a PK, and after linking to sql server, you can open up the linked table in access. Test if edits work, test if adding works, and even perhaps test if delete works. Only AFTER such time, do you now want to start testing any code or other operations from the Access client side.

Introduction of using a linked table from another application? That is a foggy area, but I can confirm for example that say .net oleDB provider will and can open a access database and use + consume even linked tables.

You also don't mention if you using sql logon, or windows auth for the sql server linked tables. But if you using sql logons, then when linking a table, you see this check box - and you want to ensure you selected this when linking the table(s) in question:

[image]

Note that you ONLY get this prompt on the first time create of the table link - additional use of the linked table manager (such as re-fresh links) does not offer this prompt. If you don't select the save password option, then you often see a sql logon prompt when you attempt to open a linked table in access.